# How to sort & display files and folders within folder

Tags: php, glob

So, This is my current code so far:

```
<?php
$path = 'Files';
$scan = scandir($path);
foreach($scan as $file)
  switch ($file) {
      case '.':
        echo "";
        break;
       case '..':
        echo "";
        break;
       case 'Thumbs.db':
        echo "";
        break;
      default:
        if (strpos($file, '.') == false) {
            echo 'folder.jpg';
        } else {
            echo  'file.jpg';
        }
    echo ' - <a href="'.$path.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></br>';
    break;
}
?>
```

So,
The idea is that after filtering out '.' , '..' and 'Thumbs.db' it displays the remaining items of the folder with either a folder or file icon next to it.
My question, is how do I get all the folders listed on the top and the files on the bottom? 
My thought was to just glob the folders first, and then glob the files so they were listed one after the other. But I wasn't sure how to write that out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just create two arrays, one for files and the other for folders

```
$folders = array_filter($scan, function($f) {
    return $f != '.' && $f != '..' && is_dir($f);
});
$files = array_filter($scan, function($f) {
    return $f != 'Thumbs.db' && is_file($f);
});
```

Then you can just iterate over each array, folders first, then files.